# Why did Microsoft choose the word "Recycle Bin"?

Tags: windows-os, names, naming

If you delete something in Windows OS, it will go to Recycle bin. But if you think about it nothing recycles in it right?

Say, you delete a virus infected file and again restore it from recycle bin it won't get *recycled* or disinfected! right?

So why name it *"recycle"*? I think Mac or Linux gets it right with *Trash*.

Comment: I don't think "trash" is a good word. "Recycle bin" is better since it denotes the fact that you can take the file back if needed

Comment: "Trash" was not working so well for Mac. At least not by the time Microsfoft choose "Recycling Bin". Mac had to call it "Wastebasket" in English-GB and English-International editions. That for sure was making for a lot of headache in all books and instructional materials.

Comment: Well, technically you do "recycle" the only resource that a file uses: Disk space. Granted, personally I think it's silly to "recycle" a non-scarce, inexpensive resource. It's not like when you empty the so-called "Recycling bin" the truck takes your files to the recycling facility, while files in Mac's "Trash" are just dumped into the landfill and you never get the space back until they rot after a few years.

Comment: Probably the same reason TiVo has a "Recently Deleted" folder where storage is eventually automatically reclaimed from (before deleting other shows) instead of a "Garbage" folder where you have to manually empty it for the machine to keep working. Keep in mind that the Recycle Bin has a fixed maximum size too, older items may automatically be deleted from the bin by Windows to make room for new items (assuming the new item is small enough to fit by itself).

Comment: @Superbest you never get people throwing all their files in the trash because they think it's environmentally friendly.

Comment: @Olaf The word "trash" is perfectly well understood in British English so the problems you describe Apple having were entirely of their own making. Indeed, choosing "wastebasket" is very odd since that term is very rare in British English, too -- people just talk about the bin.

Comment: Am I the only person who thinks the words "Empty recycle bin" are poorly chosen?  It sounds far too much like you're going to tip out the bin's contents onto the floor, so you can find the thing you didn't mean to delete.  "Oh dear, I just deleted a file that I didn't mean to.  I'd better empty out my recycle bin so I can get it back."  Or maybe it's just me.

Comment: @DavidWallace count me in.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc No, the term "recycle bin" does not denote that you can take the item back. Taking an item back from a recycle bin isn't called recycling, especially when the item is used for the same purpose or a closely-related purpose; recycling is the process which happens when the recycling people empty your recycle bin and take the stuff away.  Items can be taken back from trash bins or from recycle bins alike, but taking them back from recycle bins is usually more sanitary, because recycle bins tend not to contain raw, organic garbage such as decomposing food remains.

Comment: I've protected the question. There are too many more-or-less duplicate answers saying the same thing coming in for it that just add noise to the overall post.

Comment: Microsoft cares about the environment, and wants you to recycle instead of taking all your files to a landfill. (end joke)

Comment: Incidentally, the Japanese Recycle Bin in Windows is called「ごみ箱」 or *trash can.*

Comment: In AmigaOS (which dates back to the end of 1980s) it was called Trashcan, too.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Before and during the development of Windows 95, Microsoft was being sued by Apple for allegedly having improperly copied the Mac OS GUI.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Computer,_Inc._v._Microsoft_Corp:

> Apple lost all claims in the Microsoft suit except for the ruling that the trash can icon
> and folder icons from Hewlett-Packard's NewWave windows application were infringing.

Based on this, I conclude that Microsoft chose the "Recycle Bin" metaphor to avoid, as much as possible, the risk of being accused of infringing on Apple's "Trash".

Comment: I feel like there's some pun-like humor in this.

Comment: @leigero: Concerning the *Bin* part, which could be a pun related to *Binaries*? I've always wondered about whether that was intentional, too.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I think he's comparing "Apple's 'Trash'" to a piece of trash.

Comment: Although I think this is a very important point, technically this answer really just tells us why MS *did* *not* choose "Trash", not why they chose "Recycling Bin" instead. They could have chosen something else.

Comment: @Luke what wold they have chosen? The real world metaphors are not exactly numerous. Drain? Toilet?  A Recycle Bin is a better metaphor than a Trash Can, because recovering accidentally discarded stuff from recycle bins is somewhat cleaner than recovering it from trash cans. Also, when the trash or recycle bin or whatever is "emptied", the bits are in fact perfectly recycled for making new files.

Comment: @Kax I like 'toilet'! Think of the interactions and sound effects!

Answer (score 36):

Much of what Microsoft initiated with Windows 95, including the Start Menu, served primarily to differentiate it from Mac OS, which in the popular mindset was the only OS competing with Windows.

This coupled with the rise in attention to ecological needs in the 1990s made the term "Recycle Bin" an apt way to accomplish this differentiation, without serving any specific UX need.

Comment: I agree with you, I don't think that there was any UX choice there...

Comment: "Much of what Microsoft initiated with Windows 95 ... served primarily to differentiate it from Mac OS"[citation needed]

Comment: You cited differentiation but didn't explain from what. Please add the name of the *Recycle bin* on Mac OS at this time.

Comment: I think that's true. Like Windows putting icons on the right instead of left. You want your windows on the right since you read right to left, so putting the icons on the left is natural. But it had to be different (for whatever reason), so they go on the right.

Answer (score 16):

If you take a tomato back out of a real-life recycle bin, it also doesn't get recycled. Nor does it get disinfected (unless you actively do that).

However, if you leave it in there and the bin gets emptied, both eventually get recycled. The tomato the traditional way, the file because its bits on your hard disk get made available again for storing other files.

So recycling is actually a close metaphor to the actual behaviour, more so than the "trash".

Comment: The current content of the file is "trash", the storage it occupies is "recyclable" :-)

Comment: I'm not convinced of that explanation. I always thought the *recycling* taking place must be the action of restoring a file, not of permanently deleting it. Note that you put stuff into the recycle bin specifically for being able to restore it. If *recycling* were about the bits becoming available again, then *deleting* a file should be named *recycling*, whereas *placing something in the recycle bin*, it is effectively *not* making the bits available again until the bin happens to be emptied (which, for some users, can take a loooong time ;-) ).

Comment: @O. R. Mapper The primary definitions for the word "recycle" on Merriam-Webster imply that an object is in some way *made into something new*. (The closest to your meaning is "use again", but that's the 3rd in the list) What you're talking about would more aptly be called "restore".

Comment: @uliwitness: Then why is *delete* (as in, immediate deletion, without using the recycle bin) not named *recycle*?

Comment: Because the "delete" key has "delete" written on it and they didn't want to change all keyboard hardware? Keep in mind, the original implementation of this (in MacOS) called it Trash, not Recycle. Even though you *could* take items back out. The command there wasn't called "delete" (which would be immediate) but "Move to Trash".

Comment: A literal metaphor, perhaps, but in terms of a GUI metaphor, they're pretty much equal. It's very clear to the user that this is 'going away'. Whether one throws something in the trash vs. recycle bin, it's gone, and that's all the user cares about.

Comment: @uliwitness: Funnily, the "delete" key moves files into the recycle bin instead of "deleting" them. (Only Shift + "delete" key immediately deletes.) So, what does it have to do with the "delete" key?

Answer (score 12):

I am not sure when Windows introduced that word, but if it was since Windows 95, as Bart Gijssens's answer claims, then Microsoft is not the first one to come up with the idea of recycling. NeXT STEP operating system introduced at around 1988 had a recycling mark as the icon for its counterpart. Microsoft may have gotten the idea from there. Your question should be attributed to NeXT computer, not Microsoft.

[image]
(Image taken from http://www.fanboy.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/nextstep-os.jpg)

Comment: You can also see from that screenshot that Microsoft lifted the design of the Windows 95 window controls from NeXTSTEP.

Answer (score 9):

In Windows, the recycle bin was introduced in Windows 95. ([source used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trash_%28computing%29))

Of course, Microsoft took their idea from other OS'es that had it long before. On most OS'es, dragging a file to the trashcan meant: Delete the file.

This is where the word "recycle" comes in. Microsoft was looking for a way to make clear that moving items to the trash does not delete those items. They are "stored" in the trash for later deletion. It's only when the user empties trash that the items are deleted. Or you can restore the items to their original location. And that's what they mean with "recycling".

Comment: That was definitely not the case for the Mac (arguably the first to popularize having a trash instead of just pressing the delete key). What OSes do you know that immediately delete files put in the trash?

Comment: DOS command prompt (erase command).

Comment: It also could be "recycling" your harddrive space.

Comment: @PhilPerry not only DOS, Unix `rm` command also deletes the file permanently

Comment: @uliwitness OS/2 in 1992 had the "shredder" which immediately deleted any file dropped on it. [Here are screenshots of OS/2 2.0](http://toastytech.com/guis/os220.html), including one of [the default desktop, showing the shredder icon (bottom right)](http://toastytech.com/guis/os220desktop.png).

Comment: @uliwitness well, Windows deletes immediately in several cases: if there's no room (memory) to store in the trash, or if you're deleting a file on a server-mount which doesn't allow you to dump to a "global" recycle bin.

Comment: @uliwitness: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari_TOS, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AmigaOS, http://toastytech.com/guis/os24.html

Comment: @Luke: The hard drive space is "recycled" much more immediately when directly deleting a file, explicitly circumventing the recycle bin. I think the explanation by this answer, that *recycling* refers to files which are restored from the recycle bin again, is much more likely.

Comment: [citation needed]

Comment: Everyone answering DOS or Unix command prompt: We're talking about use of the "Trash can" icon and metaphor here, not about general deletion. Similarly, if the recycle bin actually occasionally deletes its contents, that is not an argument in favor of the claim that the "trash" icon always meant "delete immediately" at the time.

Comment: @uliwitness: so how about everybody answering TOS, AmigaOS, OS/2 just to name a few?

Answer (score 6):

I can't speak for Microsoft, but I've always liked the recycling bin metaphor as it works on so many levels:

- Recycling is more eco-friendly than garbage and the recycling bin metaphor is a form of corporate green-washing. By aligning themselves with a recycling bin instead of the more ubiquitous trashcan, Microsoft is implying something about their corporate culture and motivations.
- Recycle bins, as a concept, are less likely to disgust than trash cans are. Imagining an overflowing trash and you're thinking of a wasteful community, perhaps even of rodents and disease. An overflowing recycling bin can inspire the idea of an clean, efficient, and futuristic community.
- When you empty it, you aren't throwing away the hard drive space... you're making it available to be used again. This is a direct analog to recycling.

Comment: I doubt item 3 is the *recycling* that was meant here. When you delete a file, specifically *without* using the recycle bin, the hard drive space is made available to be used again immediately. As opposed to putting something in the recycle bin, where the hard drive space is still occupied for the time being.

Answer (score 4):

As discussed at the time:

Microsoft considered the word "trash", considered that the reason for having this was to allow people to take things back out of the "trash" before they were permanently discarded, considered that many people have a "yuck!" reaction to the idea of putting their hands into the trash bin (thinking of it as kitchen trash or otherwise unpleasant)...

... and decided that "recycle bin" avoided the yuck factor.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: Presentations by MS staff at the time Windows NT was announced. I don't have a written citation, but it was Very Explicitly Discussed In These Terms.

Comment: @keshlam But wasn't the term introduced before NT?

Comment: I'm sure you're (at least partially) correct, just not sure if 'VEDITT' counts as a cited source.

Comment: @Superbest Windows NT [hit the market in July 1993](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT#Releases).

Comment: Feel free not to consider it a cited source. It may lead someone to a citable source, however, if that's your goal.

Comment: If true--interesting! And really silly, as we're talking digital files. There's no 'yuck' involved.

Comment: Remember, we're talking about UX here. The user interface is _all_ metaphors.

Answer (score 4):

The files which are deleted are in fact recycled. The material from which they are made -- storage bits -- is regrouped and reused for other files, just like recycled plastic can be used to make something new, like a synthetic fiber sweater.

The metaphor is **much** older than Microsoft Windows.

"Garbage collection" was introduced in the late 1950's in the Lisp programming language.

But in fact garbage collection performs recycling (the term typically used is "storage reclamation"). Digital objects which have become "garbage" are turned into storage for new objects.

Memory and disk storage are a "serially reusable" resource: when a program no longer needs it, another one can use it.

Recycling of computer storage is in fact a more perfect form of recycling than, say, plastic or paper which are usually only "downcycling": recovering an inferior form of raw material compared to the original.

The recycle bin doesn't actually recycle anything, just like a real recycle bin where items sit until the real disposal takes place which initiates the recycling process. Just like a real recycling bin, the Windows one lets us change our minds: the same way we can take back a plastic bottle from our recycle bin, we can restore a deleted file.  This restore action is not understood as recycling: in computing it is called "recovery" and in physical disposal it is usually called "reuse", rather than "recycling".  (Though, by metonymy, sometimes the reuse of materials is referred to recycling; something made of re-used objects which were never actually thrown away is sometimes said to be "made of recycled goods".  However, these goods are not reused for their original purpose. If we use a plastic beverage bottle for carrying drinking water, that is not called recycling.)

When we "empty the recycle bin", that is analogous to someone taking away our recycled material to a recycling center. At that point, the opportunity to recover a file is lost, just like the opportunity to reuse a plastic bottle.

Deleting a file without going to the recycle bin (for instance, using Shift-Delete in Windows Exporer to delete permanently) is analogous to taking an item directly to the recycling depot, bypassing the local recycle bin.  Once an item is handed over to the depot, it cannot be recovered.

The recycling analogy holds very well because computer storage is a real, physical resource; the recycling is just as real as that of plastic. Storage bits are real three-dimensional objects.  These bits have a location in space, mass, volume and so on. Why we have to recycle them is that there are only so many available in a device, which has to do with physical constraints. There being only 32Gb on a flash chip is no different from, say, there only being so many liters of water on a planet.

---

So, Microsoft has considerable technical justification in calling that system feature "Recycle Bin". Yet, it has been called "Trash" or similar in other systems. Perhaps, part of the motivation is simply to be different and to tip a hat, so to speak, to the recycling movement. The recycle bin says "I am of this age; I think about the environment, and encourage people who look at me to do the same".

Comment: I don't think that is a good explanation: The files which are deleted immediately (specifically *without* using the recycle bin) are "recycled" (based on your interpretation) much more immediately than those placed in the recycle bin.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Similarly, unwanted stuff that you take directly to a recycling facility is recycled much more immediately than something you put in a recycling box for later collection. Sorry, I don't see your point.

Comment: Unwanted stuff that you throw away *without* any recycling is not recycled at all in the real world, whereas unwanted stuff that you permanently delete without going through recycle-anything in Windows is immediately recycled (in terms of free disk storage space). My point is that there are two ways to delete files - via recycle bin, and directly. With your interpretation of what *recycling* refers to - storage space - both of those methods involve recycling. When interpreting *recycling* as referring to restoring temporarily-deleted files, recycling only occurs with the one deletion ...

Comment: ... method that is called *recycle*-something. Hence, the latter seems to be more convincing as an explanation for the name.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Recycling never refers to restoring deleted files (pulling them out of the recycle bin). Similarly, if you change you mind about some plastic bottle and pull it back out of your recycle bin, that is not recycling; it is called reuse. See the popular motto, "Reduce, Reuse, Recycle!". Permanent deletion in Windows is recycling. Just like if you take a plastic bottle to a recycling facility, you will never see it again; but if you put it into your own recycle box, you have an opportunity to change your mind.

Comment: Just my word, permanent deletion in Windows is "recycling" in terms of storage space. Hence, it is not a special trait of the "recycle bin". The distinguishing trait of the "recycle bin" is that files can be restored, so it makes more sense to think that the name refers to that special trait. No, it is not a 1:1 match with the real world; as all such metaphors, the analogy is limited - just think of "folders" (directories), which, in contrast to the real world, can contain nested folders and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason is probably since when you're deleting a file, you're not recycling the file, you're recycling the hard drive space and making it available for use.

Also, the use of the term "recycle bin" is more environmentally friendly than a trash can, and might imply something about goals Microsoft may or may not make to help the environment be less contaminated with waste.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good explanation: When you *delete* a file permanently, you explicitly do *not* put it into the recycle bin, but that is when the disk space gets "recycled" (based on your interpretation) immediately. Contrast with, when you put a file into the recycle bin, and you never empty it (which most certainly happens on quite some systems ;-) ), the hard disk space never gets "recycled". (Under-the-hood tricks with compression aside, but *some* space will still be occupied.)

Comment: Well, in a real recycle bin, the files aren't really recycled until the bin is emptied.

Comment: But when deleting files immediately, *without* using the recycle bin, the disk space in use is made reusable just as well. Thus, making the disk space usable again is *not* the distinguishing factor of the recycle bin. Restoring files, on the other hand, is.

Comment: I guess deleting a file permanently without going through the recycle bin is like sending an item directly to a recycling company... I'm not sure what else to say. I don't usually delete files permanently like this, I put them in the Recycle Bin and later permanently delete them.

Answer (score 2):

I've got no actual references for this but it fits closer with Microsoft Office paradigm. In the workplace (possibly still Microsoft's largest user base), users were mainly using their computers for word processing and spreadsheets. Paper is a recyclable material and hence you should be putting paper in a recycling bin rather than general waste.

Comment: For me, this is the most considered and likely answer to the question of why Recycling Bin was chosen.

Answer (score 1):

It is called a 'Recycling Bin' because the files in it can be taken out at any moment, unless you bypass the recycling bin and delete it straight away by holding the SHIFT key while performing an action that would normally send a file to the trash. The fact that you can restore and 'recycle' your work back onto your computers hard drive.

Comment: This isn't really saying anything that other answers here already have - [such as Bart's post from a few days ago](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/55944/3865).

Comment: There isn't much to say that Bart hasn't already mentioned though. I was just giving a simplified explanation.

Comment: It also doesn't really address the metaphor differences, as you can take something out of the trash as easily as the recycle bin.